# How to instantiate an association to a service class based on the contract hierarchy?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to instantiate an association to a service class based on the contract hierarchy. Consider following code:

```
public interface IServiceBase
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IService : IServiceBase
{
    void DoSomeOtherthing();
}

public interface IOtherService : IServiceBase
{
    void DoAnotherthing();
}
public class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base service implementation");
    }
}
public class Service : ServiceBase, IService
{
    public void DoSomeOtherthing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New service implementation");
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine("Child service implementation");
    }
}
public class OtherService : ServiceBase, IOtherService
    {
        public void DoAnotherthing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Another child service implementation");
        }
    }
public abstract class ClientBase
{
    public IServiceBase Service { get; set; }
}

public class Client : ClientBase
{
    public IService Service { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClient : ClientBase
{
    public IOtherService Service { get; set; }
}
```

If an IoC container try to inject Service property of ClientBase, it will find two types that are registered as IServiceBase: IService and IOtherService. 
How IoC can decide to use which type is proper for instatiation? This decision depends on Client concrete class: Client or OtherClient which they know to which inherited interface they actually depend on: IService or IOtherService corresponds to Service or OtherService type.

Comment: I've dropped my answer. Please try to rephrase the entire question so I can clearly understand what's going on...

Comment: Ok, now I should ask: what's the problem itself then? What do you want to get with your question? :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer -- If an IoC container try to inject Service property of ClientBase, it will find two types that are registered as IServiceBase: IService and IOtherService. how it will decide to use which type for instatiation. This decision depends on Client concrete class: Client or OtherClient which they know to which inherited interface they actually depend on: IService or IOtherService corresponds to Service or OtherService type.

Comment: So.. why don't you rephrase again your question? Your concern is just what you've said on this last comment. Be more concrete when you ask questions: *I've this concern because A, B, C*.

Comment: OK! I rephrased the question. It would be nice if you can help improving the question.

Comment: Now's a better and more specific question! Let's answer it

Comment: Check my answer, I hope that now I could address your concern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up to a solution which encapsulates composition logic in a Resolver(Composer) class; accompanied by some contract on property definition for services.
We define Lazy properties which T is type of service interface. As I fixed up following code:

```
public interface IServiceBase
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IService : IServiceBase
{
    void DoSomeOtherthing();
}

public interface IOtherService : IServiceBase
{
    void DoAnotherthing();
}
public class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base service implementation");
    }
}
public class Service : ServiceBase, IService
{
    public void DoSomeOtherthing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New service implementation");
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        base.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine("Child service implementation");
    }
}
public class OtherService : ServiceBase, IOtherService
    {
        public void DoAnotherthing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Another child service implementation");
        }
    }
public abstract class ClientBase
{
    private IServiceResolver _serviceResolver;
    public ClientBase()
    {
        _serviceResolver = new ServiceResolver();
        _serviceResolver.Resolve(this);
    }
    [Resolve(isParentContract:true)]
    public Lazy<IServiceBase> Service { get; set; }
}

public class Client : ClientBase
{
    [Resolve]
    public Lazy<IService> Service { get; }
}

public class OtherClient : ClientBase
{
    [Resolve]
    public Lazy<IOtherService> Service { get; }
}
```

The ServiceResolver responsibility is to find all Lazy properties which marked by Resolve attribute and create a Lazy instance of the true contract which is infer-able by matching contracts to parent service contract. This way the property which is marked by ResolveAttribute as *isParentContract:true* will be instantiated by the key of type a property which is defined in inherited client class and it's interface type is inherited from type of property defined in parent client.

Answer (score 0):

Usually IoC/DI containers configure a concrete service interface. They don't automatically handle an injection of `IService` even if you've already configured `IOtherService` when that last interface implements `IService` too. That is, it can only inject a direct implementation of `IOtherService`.

For example, in *Castle Windsor* you register an implementation for more than one service at once as follows:

```
container.Register
(
     // OtherService implements these interfaces, right?
     Component.For<IServiceBase, IService, IOtherService>()
              .ImplementedBy<OtherService>()
);
```

That is, once `OtherService` gets injected in a component on which the type is `IServiceBase`, `IService` or `IOtherService`, the container will be able to resolve `OtherService`.

Comment: OtherService does not implement IService interface. The point is that if IService is being resolved for ClientBase class, by some trick IoC container should look at the concrete class Service property type to find out the exact interface type of service to get resolved.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat Hmmm? But `IOtherService` implements `IService` and `IService` implements `IServiceBase`. Therefore, `IOtherService` is also `IService` and `IServiceBase`.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat There's no trick here. If `OtherService` implements `IOtherService`, if you use `is` operator `otherService is IService` or `otherService is IServiceBase` you should get `true` anyway

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat See: `IOtherService : IServiceBase`. Now check my previous comment about the `is` operator.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat Also `typeof(IServiceBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IOtherService))` will return `true`